# How to use "lead" in sentence?

Tags: grammar

How can we use *lead* in the sentences like below?

> Foreign tourists encourage the locals to learn their language that probably leads to generate more income.

The verb after *leads* should bring in *-ing* form?

Comment: _Leads_ needs an object ('leads [someone] to generate income'), but it isn't clear who that someone is, so it would be better to say, as Andrew suggests, _leads to the generation of more income_.

Comment: 'Foreign tourists encourage the locals to learn their language' is ambiguous, and if it means 'Foreign tourists encourage the locals to learn their different languages' is puzzling. I can't see the desires of the tourists as a significant driving force. Perhaps 'Locals find it best to learn the different major languages of the tourists'. // 'This in all probability leads to the generation of more income for the local economy'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The *to* is a preposition ("leads to") and not a particle ("to generate"). Because it's a preposition, it needs to be followed by a noun phrase.

There are two nouns phrases you could have:

> ...leads to **the generation of more income.**
> ...leads to **generating more income.**

What *generating* here **actually is** is something about which there [has been debate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205390/what-is-a-gerund-a-noun-or-a-verb-his-smoking-upset-me). I would say it's a gerund; others might disagree.

Comment: The sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I answered the part that was asked about. And actually, it's not ungrammatical. It talks of "their language that probably leads to generating more income." It's nonsense, but not ungrammatical.

Comment: 'Foreign tourists encourage the locals to learn their language; this probably leads to the generation of more income' is fine.

Comment: It makes sense. What is there at the moment doesn't mean much but it is grammatical. The *that* clause describes the particular language which the locals are encouraged to learn.

Comment: I don't accept that. Foreign tourists will have a multiplicity of native languages, so 'their language that ...' doesn't work. It has to be 'the one of their languages that ...'.

Comment: The *their* in the sample sentence refers to the locals, not the tourists, and it is talking about the locals' language that generates more income. **It is grammatical.** While it almost certainly doesn't have the meaning the writer intended, you seem to be concentrating on what has not been asked about.

Comment: OP needs to realise that the sentence needs more adjustment than merely changing to 'that probably leads to _the generation of more / the optimal generation of_ income. I see ELL as a place where teaching is the priority, unlike ELU where the building of a databank of sound practice and analysis is the aim.

Comment: Fine. **Write an answer then.** My answer is (or was, anyway) an ELU answer, where we don't do proofreading -- and the intended meaning isn't mentioned anyway.